# Trigger update panel to refresh gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax

I have two update panels on my page. The first has a form that contains required field validators and a button that triggers the update panel and sends the info to a database. It also has a trigger for the button.

The second update panel holds a gridview that shows a few columns from the collected data. As of right now I have the gridviews update panel set to conditional and its trigger is the button that submits the first form. It's supposed to work on the click event, but the gridview isn't updating.

In other words, I want the gridview to update when I insert a new record through the form in the first update panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code behind for the button that submits the form add GridView1.DataBind(); at the end. Now changes will be reflected automatically in the gridview. Pretty neat.